# Fringe spacing of the Interference pattern due to two in-falling coherent waves

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, interference

It has been a long time since I have dealt with these kinds of interference/fringewidth problem, I cant figure out a way to start solving this problem. I was thinking about what the spacing between each of these wave-lines signify, and exactly which of them would create the pattern. Because of its oblique incidence, each wave would individually create patterns, so how do the two patterns make a final one?i think the fringewidth of the final pattern is asked here!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are asked about the superposition of two sets of plane wavefronts.

I have redrawn part of the diagram which shows some wavefronts at an instant in time, ie like a photograph.

[image]

$k_1$ and $k_2$ are two rays with wavefronts (eg crests) perpendicular to the rays and one wavelength apart shown in the same colour as the corresponding rays.

What does the diagram look like after half a period and one period?

So where are the positions of constructive interference?

Comment: Yes, The incident point is the 1st interference maxima, then second maxima is the point right/left where the next wavefronts of the waves hits together.

Comment: @BaibhabBose A bit of trigonometry will get you the answer to your question.

Comment: The two pointy angles of the rhombuses with the longer diagonals along x axis are 30 . We need those diagonals, =2Lcos30, where L=sides of that rhombus. and again the wavelength lambda=Lcos30 from more geometry. finally the diagonal=the spacing=1um. Is that right?

Comment: The correct answer is given 0.5$\mu$m